# Fix Code to Append Expanded Numbers Properly

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm having an issue with my current code.

```
Sub ExpandRanges()

Dim X As Long, CG As Variant, Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim Series As String, CommaGroups() As String, DashGroups() As String
Dim j As Long, lastrow As Long

j = 0
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Range(Range("H2"), Range("H" & lastrow))

For Each Cell In Rng

CommaGroups = Split(Cell, ",")

For Each CG In CommaGroups

    DashGroups = Split(CG, "-")

    For X = DashGroups(0) To DashGroups(UBound(DashGroups))
        If j = 0 Then j = Split(Cell.Address, "$")(2)

        Rows(j + 1 & ":" & j + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Cells(j, 9).Value = X

        Range("A" & j + 1 & ":H" & j + 1).Value = Range("A" & j & ":H" & j).Value

        j = j + 1
    Next

Next

Next

'Band-aid solution
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & lastrow & ":H" & lastrow).ClearContents

End Sub
```

It currently is expanding the number range for only ONE range of numbers in my excel file, any time I try to add another range it will freeze and not respond.

For example, here is my input data for just one row:

[Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zvg4.png)

When I run my code, this is my output which is exactly what I want:

[Correct Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RyIn.png)

But now the issue is, whenever I got to add another row of number ranges like this:

[Added Ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzrCK.png)

My excel pane will freeze and tell me it is not responding.

Any ideas on how to format the code to be able to append all the expanded ranges in new rows? Thanks!!

Comment: You should generally avoid modifying a collection while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were most of the way there. I've assumed your data starts in Sheet1 and cell H2. This code removes the original row. I haven't added any code to increment PPKLaneID etc. But the structure is generally there.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Expand()

    Dim vSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vRow As Long
    Dim vOriginalRow As Long
    Dim vCounter As Long
    Dim vCommaGroup As Variant
    Dim vCommaGroups() As String
    Dim vDashGroups() As String

    ' Assume data is in Sheet1 and starts in cell H2 ...
    Set vSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    vRow = 2
    While vSheet.Cells(vRow, 8) <> ""

        ' If this group doesn't contain a dash, then it is single value and not a range
         If InStr(1, vSheet.Cells(vRow, 13), "-") <> 0 Then

            ' Remember the original row as this will be deleted
            vOriginalRow = vRow

            ' Split up the comma groups (can be 1 or more)
            vCommaGroups = Split(vSheet.Cells(vRow, 13), ",")
            For Each vCommaGroup In vCommaGroups()

                ' Split into dash groups
                vDashGroups = Split(vCommaGroup, "-")
                For vCounter = CLng(vDashGroups(LBound(vDashGroups))) To CLng(vDashGroups(UBound(vDashGroups)))

                    ' create space to insert the new data
                    Rows(vRow + 1 & ":" & vRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

                    ' Duplicate data in columns H through L
                    Range("H" & vRow & ":L" & vRow).Copy Range("H" & CStr(vRow + 1) & ":L" & CStr(vRow + 1))

                    ' and in column M put the number from the range being looped through
                    Range("M" & CStr(vRow + 1)) = vCounter
                    vRow = vRow + 1
                Next
            Next

            ' Delete the original row
            Rows(vOriginalRow).Delete

        End If

        vRow = vRow + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

So from this ...

[image: screen1]

To this ...

[image: screen2]

Comment: wait nevermind :( it's not giving me an output at all

Comment: Could you reformat this to where my PK lane ID starts in column A and my output ranges are column H? I believe this is what is messing me up

Comment: Okay never mind, I figured that one out! But for some reason, my output does not look like yorus