# VBScript for splitting rows by cartesian product

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file which is generated by another program.
I need to split and extract the Excel rows in that way:

the source:

[image]

the Excel after the "split" action should be:

[image]

the way to do this is clear for me- but I didn't manage to write it in VB 
the logic should be:
we have 3 columns: name, servers, accounts -> the results will contain a cartesian product of `servers X accounts` for each 'name'.

```
int Count1=1 loop for counting the number of column B (servers-separated by comma)
int Count2=1 loop for counting the number of column C (accounts-separated by comma)

1 loop i=1 from i to count1(servers)

for each server
loop: j=1 from j to count2(account)
create a new row(column A:=Name, column B:=server[i],coulmn c:=account[j]) 

move to next row
```

I just need help with syntax.

Comment: Try using this answer as an example of the syntax required: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264996/fix-code-to-append-expanded-numbers-properly/52268437#52268437

Comment: I would suggest the following: Decide which language you want to use (VBScript or VBA). Immerse yourself in a tutorial for that language. Record the basic operations outlined in your pseudocode as one or more macro(s). Edit the macro(s) to form the desired end result. In that order.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR(), vS(1 To 2), s
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, n As Long
    Dim c1 As Integer, c2 As Integer

    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        vS(1) = Split(vDB(i, 2), ",")
        vS(2) = Split(vDB(i, 3), ",")
        If InStr(vDB(i, 2), ",") Then
            c1 = 1
            c2 = 2
        Else
            c1 = 2
            c2 = 1
        End If

        For Each s In vS(c1)
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 3, 1 To n)
            vR(1, n) = vDB(i, 1)
            vR(c1 + 1, n) = s
            vR(c2 + 1, n) = vS(c2)(0)
        Next s
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(n, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)

End Sub
```